# Any public API to accept an image with a UPC barcode and return product code?

Tags: api, barcode, barcode-scanner

Could anyone please suggest me of any public API (free or otherwise) which can accept some binary image having upc barcode and return me the underlying product code therein?

I wish to consume one from within a .net application + smartphone applications e.g. iPhone, Android etc.

Answer (score 1):

(I know it's an old question, but just saw it:)

You can upload images to http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx (or programmatically post to the same URLs that this web form does). This is a service we (I) run for free as a benefit for the public, so please don't flood it with requests.

If you like it and want to send a load of requests, you can run your own instance of it. The full source code is available at http://code.google.com/p/zxing; see the `zxingorg/` folder.